# Linear probability model with fixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, plm, economics

If I want to estimate a **linear probability model with (region) fixed effects**, is that the same as just running a fixed effects regression? Maybe I'm getting tripped up with the language. My goal is to estimate the effect of a baby bonus. My dependent variable is a binary indicator for NEWBORN and my main independent variable of interest is an indicator for receiving the baby bonus. I control for age, age squared, education, marital status, and household income.

Should I be using:

```
## 1.) Linear Probability    
LPM <- lm(newborn ~ treatment + age + age_sq + highest_education + marital_stat + 
            hh_income_log, data=fertility_15_45)
```

or

```
## 2.) FE Model      
FE_model <- plm(newborn ~ treatment + age + age_sq + highest_education + marital_stat + 
                  hh_income_log, data = fertility_15_45, index="region", model="within")
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Has been posted here as well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462437/linear-probability-model-with-fixed-effects

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add a region dummy in your LPM to get region fixed effects. *Example:*

```
library(plm)
data(Cigar)

summary(plm(I(sales > 121.2) ~ price + pop, data=Cigar, model="within", index="state"))$coe
#            Estimate   Std. Error     t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# price -2.880255e-03 2.626505e-04 -10.9661107 7.519348e-27
# pop   -6.922327e-06 1.311006e-05  -0.5280165 5.975758e-01

summary(lm(I(sales > 121.2) ~ 0 + price + pop + factor(state), data=Cigar))$coe[1:2, ]
#            Estimate   Std. Error     t-value     Pr(>|t|)
# price -2.880255e-03 2.626505e-04 -10.9661107 7.519348e-27
# pop   -6.922327e-06 1.311006e-05  -0.5280165 5.975758e-01
```